# Why is the TV Daario Naharis much less flamboyant?

Tags: character, game-of-thrones, book-adaptation

In the book, Daario Naharis is described as such:

> Daario keeps his beard cut in three prongs, all dyed blue. His eyes are blue and his curly hair is dyed blue. His mustachios are painted gold and he has a large, curving nose. He is lithe, smooth skinned, has a golden tooth and dresses in loud colors and finery. He wears a Dothraki arakh on his left hip and a Myrish stiletto on his right hip. Their hilts are a matched pair of naked women made in gold.

In the TV series, his appearance is much more normal. Why is that?
I don't think it's a question of budget as GoT is a really successful series.

Comment: This seems to be the general approach they take for stuff that's just too _exotic_, usually Essos related. I think they are afraid that even though it works in the books, it may appear too grotesque on screen. Other examples are Astapori not having weird haircuts, Quarth women not exposing one breast, [Vargo Hoat's equivalent](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Locke) not riding a [zebra](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Zorse), etc.

Comment: Just because something is successful doesn't mean it doesn't have a budget. I'm sure actor comfort was taken into account as well.

Comment: Why are any of the show characters different from the book?

Comment: @Skooba, you're right, but in this case, GoT does have a substancial budget.

Comment: @cde, some characters (Naharis is one of them) as extremely different from the books. Including differences that can't be explained simply by casting choices.

Comment: Keep in mind Daario was recasted from a blond to the current prince of Persia lookalike.

Comment: Better yet, why don't the Boltons wear pink? Not "manly" enough for HBO?

Comment: When Ed Skrein was playing Daario he WAS quite flamboyant and extremely cocky. When Michiel Huisman took over the role the character changed. It had me so confused at first. I couldn't figure out who he was since not only the actor changed but the character changed too.

Comment: @tom, I'm mostly asking about his physical appearance.

Comment: Skrein's version of the character had the long blond wig with braids. Although the specifics of the book are different, I'd say [this picture](http://static2.hypable.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/ed-skrein-daario-game-of-thrones.png) says flamboyant. Compare that to [Huisman in essentially the same costume](https://i.guim.co.uk/img/static/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/1/31/1391190436395/Michiel-Huisman-008.jpg?w=300&q=55&auto=format&usm=12&fit=max&s=dab564e1cb9bee681e060d43da2c9e9e) but with fewer embellishments and he has shorter hair and a scruffy beard. This does not say flamboyant

Comment: [Here's](https://youtu.be/GdxBOpP1bIo?t=231) an interesting take on how he would like if the showrunners stayed true to the book.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A big part of Daario's story is that Dany is very attracted to him. In the books, she is a 14 year old girl who finds his flamboyant style different, mysterious, and intriguing.

It's easy to convey her attraction through text, but the shows are a visual medium. Therefore, Daario needs to be more conventionally attractive, so that the TV watching audience isn't alienated.

If Daario was shown as he was in the books, his look would be stylistically similar to the following picture. While I think that he's not a bad looking guy, I think a large enough portion of Middle America would be turned off enough by the style and look that it was just safer for the show to go with a look that is more conventionally attractive by today's standards.

[image: guy with dyed beard and hair]

Comment: @AerisFang So far it's the only answer :-)

Comment: Great answer!  It also bothered me a great deal when the original Daario left the show.  The original actor was at least hyper-masculine (big chin, ect.) which is faithful to the behavioral characteristic of the character in book.)  The new actor is much too sensitive-looking for my tastes!